Expo - How to create a reusable cross platform component?
I am building an app with React Expo. In this app, I have a component that I want to use in other projects. This component works on Android, iOS, and Web. For demo purposes, here is a sample:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

interface MyTextBoxProps {
    value: string;
}

interface MyTextBoxState {
    inputValue: string;
}

export class MyTextBox extends Component<MyTextBoxProps, MyTextBoxState> {
    constructor(props: MyTextBoxProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputValue: props.value
        };
    }


    onInputChange = (text: string) => {
        this.setState({ inputValue: text });
    }

  render() { 
    const { inputValue } = this.state;

    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputField} value={inputValue} onChangeText={this.onInputChange}></TextInput>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputField: {
      fontSize: 14,
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  });

My question is, how do I package this component so that I can share/use them in my other projects? I tried finding a step-by-step tutorial without much success. Any direction is appreciated.

Does this answer your question? How to share react component across multiple projects?
